# How to escape a dot in the name of an array key?

Tags: laravel

I'm confused with the usage of the dot notation, I understand the following examples:

```php
Arr::get(['bar.baz' => 'X'], 'bar.baz') # returns: "X"
Arr::get(['bar' => ['baz' => 'X']], 'bar.baz') # returns: "X"
Arr::get(['foo' => ['bar.baz' => 'X']], 'foo') # returns: ["bar.baz" => "X"]
```

And I infer that the following could return `"X"`

```php
Arr::get(['foo' => ['bar.baz' => 'X']], 'foo.bar.baz') # returns null
Arr::get(['foo' => ['bar.baz' => 'X']], 'foo.bar\.baz') # returns null
```

But it doesn't, is it the expected behavior?

I know there are other ways to get that value such as using [undot](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-array-undot) strategy but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Your real question is "how to escape a dot in the name of an array key". Well the simple answer is you don't. If you look at the [Arr::get](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/38f022d01fd85caf88c11cec52dade7ccccccfdf/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php#L308) line [326](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/38f022d01fd85caf88c11cec52dade7ccccccfdf/src/Illuminate/Collections/Arr.php#L326) you'll see that it simply does `foreach (explode('.', $key) as $segment)`, which doesn't support the key structure in your array.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can add a method, such as get2 to Arr facade:

```
class AppServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Arr::macro('get2', function () {
            //here your code
        }
    }
}
```

An then use it:

```
Arr::get2(['foo' => ['bar.baz' => 'X']], 'foo.bar\.baz')
```